# Mockito mock static method

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermockito

I need to test the method myMethod in the class MyClass and in order to do so I need to intercept the nextInt call to make return a specified value. How do I do so?

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;

public class MyClass {
    public int myMethod() {
        int a = nextInt();
        return a;
    }
}
```

This is what I tried and I'd like a solutiona in this way with mockito or powerMock.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import tech.delvi.recipeBusinessLogic.MyClass;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class Prova {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        MockedStatic<RandomUtils> randomUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(RandomUtils.class);
        randomUtilsMockedStatic.when(() -> RandomUtils.nextInt()).thenReturn(1);

        MyClass myClass = mock(MyClass.class);
        assertEquals(1, myClass.myMethod());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are testing `MyClass`. Don't mock it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking (not all the time), the need of mocking `static` methods flags a bad design in the code.

If your code uses a `static` method, it means it needs exactly that method to be used no matter the usage. If however you need to mock it for tests, then maybe you don't really need a static method but an `interface` that returns something different depending on the context.

Sometimes, we simply don't have the choice (e.g. we don't control the code we're testing, and that code is using a `static` method that we need to mock) so in that case, using a mocking library to mock it is the only option left. But if the code is yours (which I think is the case), then I would design it in a way that you can mock it more easily. For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final Supplier<Integer> intSupplier;

    public MyClass(Supplier<Integer> intSupplier) {
        this.intSupplier = intSupplier;
    }

    public int myMethod() {
        int a = intSupplier.get();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Like that, in production you will do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(() -> nextInt());
```

... and in the tests, you can do:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(() -> 1);
```

Comment: @k314159 I simply meant "using a mocking library", I'll update accordingly